# React Js components dynamically change h1 tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1 className="title"><img src="back.png" className="pull-left"/>{this.props.somefield*}</h1>
     <ul className="main_menu">

      <li><Link to="/" className="active"><i className="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Dashboard</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/favorite"><i className="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Favorite</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/find"><i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Find</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/settings"><i className="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Settings</Link></li>
    </ul>
    )}
  }

}
```

The above field is used as a component and my component was used:

```
<Header *and Some fields/>
```

How do I use this in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add span or div  wrap beginning of component

```
export default class Header extends Component {

render() {


return (
 <span>
   <h1 className="title"><img src="back.png" className="pull-left"/> {this.props.name}</h1>

  <ul className="main_menu">

      <li><Link to="/" className="active"><i className="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Dashboard</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/favorite"><i className="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Favorite</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/find"><i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Find</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/settings"><i className="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>Settings</Link></li>
  </ul>
 </span> 
 );
 }
 }
```

Then App will be worked ..

Answer (score 1):

Props can be passed as *attributes*:

```
<Header someField='Foo' />

//...
render() {
  return (
    <h1 className="title">
      <img src="back.png" className="pull-left"/>
      {this.props.someFeild}
    </h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: <ul> tag adding header component then follwing error   "While building for web.browser:
   imports/ui/layout/Header.jsx:13:6: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in
   an enclosing tag "